# Database entry corruption on screen orientation change

Tags: android, android-room

I have an Android app that uses Room to work with database. In one of fragments in onViewCreated I get an object from database using simple query `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id = ?`. The id for the query is being stored in Fragment's arguments Bundle. It works fine, but when I change orientation and fragment is recreated by system, the same query returns null, and I cannot get this entry from any other query in the app.

I have checked the id, it does not disappear after change in orientation and I have used debugger to intercept all queries to the database, there were only SELECT queries, no DELETE, UPDATE or INSERT

UPD: Code

Fragment

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_lesson_client, container, false);
    ButterKnife.bind(this, view);

    lesson = App.Companion.getDb().lessonDao().getLesson(getArguments().getLong("lesson"));
```

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM Lesson WHERE id == :id")
fun getLesson(id: Long): Lesson?
```

Comment: Please add a fragment code, where you requesting your database.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov done,  or do you need full code of fragment?

Comment: I think it's enough. In SQL there is no '=='. Try with single '=' in your query.

Comment: And show your getDb method also, if my first suggest was wrong.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov I'll try that, but it doesn't explain why the query works most of the time, but stops working on a specific id after orientation change

Comment: It does not explain why it work. ) Add getDb() code please.

Comment: @AndreiVinogradov getDb isn't actually a method, it's Kotlin variable db, accessed from Java code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182043/discussion-between-andrei-vinogradov-and-loredan13).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, my problem in the first place was that there is no `@Upsert` annotation in Room and I just assumed that `@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)` does the same thing, but it's not. Instead of updating the entry it actually deletes it and inserts a new one. And it so happens that in my fragment there was a `TextWatcher` hooked up to text field, which performed said insert on an entry which was referenced by that disappearing entry from the question using `FOREIGN KEY ON DELETE CASCADE`. During orientation change that `TextWatcher` fired an event and the deletion of the entry during insert actually cascaded and removed all entries that were referencing it, which caused the problem